# Will I lose my data when I install Ubuntu alongside windows?

Tags: dual-boot, data-loss

Currently I am using windows 8.1(Trial version), but I wanted to check out Ubuntu as my trial ends within 2 months. I have 500GB HDD and half of it is filled with important Data. Now, I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside windows 8.1. Before that I wanted to make sure if I'd lose my data when I install it. The question is how do I install Ubuntu on my computer without losing data?

Comment: Hi user258957, welcome to Askubuntu. You should not lose your data, as long as you choose to install -alongside- Windows, however, I would not do anything without making a proper backup. There are many posts on the subject on askubuntu, if you use the search function, you will find many hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 you will not lose any data, I have done this in the past. P.S. If I was you I would wait an extra month for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) to come out and then install it (that's what I would do) If you have a USB backup the data aswell, just to be extra safe.